# How can i create conversion rate dashboard report for product pages with one type of information?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, reporting

I am trying to get a dashboard reporting on product pages with certain type of information (Example: Product with youtube video vs product without youtube video). So i have create a datalayer and pushes this to a GA variable.

I also have a goal (add to cart, GA event) and trying to get this conversion rate.

But i do not get any data on the goal when choosing "Page" as display column, only "Goal completion location(Same as product page). If i select Goal completion location i can not get goal conversion rate.

Any one have a idea how i can get conversion rate on this?

Comment: Some clarification questions: is your GA variable associated to the pageview? (meaning, is it set on the pageview hit, or sent separately?) Which reports are you looking at?

Comment: GA variable is set on pageview. I did test yesterday to set this on event as well. This did it possible to collect the data. But this would make the data wrong? If it only gather data if a user click add to cart? Or does it calculate right if variable is set on pageview and event?

Comment: Thank you - since the variable is about what is or isn't on the page, putting it on the pageview seems most appropriate. So, is what you want to know something like: do people click "add to cart" more on product pages with videos?

Comment: Correct @Reve, this is what i am trying to do.

Comment: Okay. I don't think goals are actually going to be the way to get the numbers you want. It will be a bit before I have the time to write up an answer, but I think you're going to want to use the actual event and pageview counts, with a calculated metric or two to find the conversion rates.